# nativescript cocoapods plugin for RealmIO and typescript

Tags: typescript, realm, nativescript

I am trying to port two native implementations of an app, to a single version based on nativescript.

The android app used SQLite, and the iOS used RealmIO for whatever reason.

To read the iOS data, I have tried creating a realmio plugin using the instructions from https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods

I.e.

1. create the package.json file (name: nativescript-realm)
2. add the Pods file in the platforms folder
3. from my main project, do `tns plugin install ../nativescript-realm`

However, whenever I try to `import { RLMRealm } from "nativescript-realm"`  from one of my typescript files , i get told "nativescript-realm" is not a module

I am unsure how to proceed. I.e. if the instructions is for building a javascript-only plugin, and I should do additional work to make it typescript aware or not.

I have tried running the `TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/tsc" tns build ios` from the main project, and in the resulting output, I see RLRealm listed.
After running this, I can get type completion to work just fine in Visual Studio Code, but if I try to use any of the classes and compile again with `tns build ios`, i get 10000 rows of
`tsc/x86_64/objc!zlib.d.ts(150,36): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'interop'.`

Which I assume is due to it trying to compile the generated bindings. I then try to remove the `tsc` folder, and build just using `tns build ios`, and get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RLMRealm'.`

Ideally, I would like the plugin to only apply to the iOS build target, but for now I need to understand what the correct approach is to building a plugin that is typescript compatible based on a cocoapods import under ios.

Comment: Do you build your plugin before installing it in your project? If you use the plugin template from NS, you will find in the package.json, the command `tns prepare plugin` which will build plugin & install it in demo project.

Comment: I did not use the template project, because the Cocoapods page says "create a package.json that looks like this: ```{
  "name": "nativescript-realm",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "nativescript": {
    "platforms": {
      "ios": "1.3.0"
    }
  }
}```

Comment: After running "TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/tsc", you only need to copy the declaration file of `RLRealm` to the `typings` folder of your project (then you can use the framework in your typescript project without compile error) & delete the folder `tsc`. Then build your project again. Plus for package.json, the NS platform version is now `5.0`

Comment: If you are writing it as a plugin within project, you don't have to explicitly install again. Have you added `tns-platform-declarations` as dev dependency and imported them in your `references.d.ts`?

Comment: Yes, after creating the typings folder, and adding the two d.ts files there, and referencing the platform typings in them, i am able to compile, and apparently start the module.  I have yet to get it to do anything interesting, but its progress.